# Unable to install and update whatsapp on my Lumia 630. It's giving me the 80073cf9 sign

Tags: whatsapp, store, app-update

I got a message that my whatsapp version has expired and that I should go to window's Store and update. It's been difficult to update and I cannot even access the version on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a [discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia/error-code-80073cf9/9c9fbd30-7e3e-4cfa-9ed5-ed4dceb4db41) in Microsoft community and an [article](http://www.techanges.com/windows-phone-error-80073cf9/) I am stating this solution. This solution aggregates the most helpful answers in the discussion and the article.

---

Try these solution one by one:

1. Whatsapp will not install on SD card. Go to Storage sense and make sure the default save location for an app is Phone memory.
2. Turn on your GPS location. Allow location permissions when asked in store.
3. Please check that your region and date settings(time zone) are correct. Verify date and time.
4. Try switching between Wi-Fi and cellular data/mobile data.
5. Follow these steps

   - Cancel all pending downloads.
   - Go to Internet Explorer/Edge and clear all Internet History, cache, etc..
   - Restart your phone.
   - Try installing apps again.

---

**Reference:**

1. [Error code 80073cf9 - Microsoft community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia/error-code-80073cf9/9c9fbd30-7e3e-4cfa-9ed5-ed4dceb4db41)
2. [Windows phone error - Techanges.com](http://www.techanges.com/windows-phone-error-80073cf9/)